# Read file in blocks instead of line-by-line?

Tags: bash

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
[1] Header information Timestamp Text begins
Text continues
Text continues
Text continues

[2] Header information Timestamp Text begins
Text continues
Text continues

[3] Header information Timestamp Text begins
Text continues
Text continues
Text continues
```

I'd like to read that file in, and process each entry (they're anywhere from 1 to 20 or 30 lines) individually.

Is there any way to loop through the file using the blank lines as a delimiter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the answer is yes!

`awk -vRS="" '...'` will treat blank line as Row spliter.

take your example and test:

```
kent$  cat b.txt
[1] Header information Timestamp Text begins
Text continues
Text continues
Text continues

[2] Header information Timestamp Text begins
Text continues
Text continues

[3] Header information Timestamp Text begins
Text continues
Text continues
Text continues

kent$  awk -vRS="" '{print "==== new block here ===="}1' b.txt  
==== new block here ====
[1] Header information Timestamp Text begins
Text continues
Text continues
Text continues
==== new block here ====
[2] Header information Timestamp Text begins
Text continues
Text continues
==== new block here ====
[3] Header information Timestamp Text begins
Text continues
Text continues
Text continues
```

Comment: Bingo! That fixed it perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure `bash` solution:

```
{
    read -r block    # First line only
    while read -r; do
        if [[ $REPLY =~ ^$ ]]; then
            # Do what you like with the contents 
            # $block here, then ...
            block=""
        else
            block+="$REPLY"
        fi
    done
 } < file.txt
```