# Loop through file and manipulate text between pattern

Tags: bash

I have a file that looks like this:

```
START
#Test
#Test
#Test
A    B    1
A    B    2
A    C    1
A    C    2
START
#Test
#Test
#Test
A    B    1
A    B    1
A    A    2
A    C    3
START
```

And continues on many more times.

What I am trying to do is loop through the file in bash so that I can manipulate the first batch of text sandwiched between 'START', write it to a file, and then move on to the next batch and do the same. And so on.

Edit:
Expected output is difficult to post but essentially I want to be able to edit the text between each 'START' so the output would just be the entire block of text but printed one block at a time so I can act on each block individually.

I tried searching for an answer and came across the code shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14736135/10586292) but it does not print the text with identical formatting to the input, as far as I could get it to work anyway.

Comment: Post the expected output.

Comment: Also provide some code, that you tried to write.

Comment: What's your question?  As asked, it seems that the obvious answer is "use `sed` or `awk`".  More details as to what you mean by "manipulate" would be helpful.

Comment: I'm doing quite a few things to the text downstream but I suppose I could post them all if it would help. I suppose the question is how do I act on one block of text at a time (treating each block as a separate file essentially) rather than the whole file at once.

Answer (score 0):

You could add NUL bytes at the end of each START line then use `split` to handle the file splitting :

```
 sed -E '/^START$/{N;s/\n/\n\x0/}' yourfile | split -t '\0' -l 1
```

With your sample input this will produce 3 files xaa xab and xac which respectively contain the section before the first START (which is empty), the second start and the third start. The filenames can be changed to more suitable values using `split`'s options.

The `sed` command is a bit more complicated than you'd think because you want to put the NUL byte after the linefeed, which requires reading the line that follows the START line in order to have the linefeed in the pattern space.

Due to this, two consecutive START lines wouldn't be handled as two sections end, instead the second START would be part of the next section.

[See it in action !](https://ideone.com/qKOati)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**awk**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) for that purpose. Let's assume that you have input file as ***test.txt***:

```
START
#Test
#Test
#Test
A    B    1
A    B    2
A    C    1
A    C    2
START
#Test
#Test
#Test
A    B    1
A    B    1
A    A    2
A    C    3
```

We will give this file as a input of awk.

```
cat test.txt | awk 'BEGIN{ RS = "" ; FS = "START\n" }{print $2}'
```

This code will split your string into batches. **RS** operator will help you to identify lines, **FS** will help you define ***START*** as a seperator. I could not clearly understand why first one is empty. But anyway you can use variables as batch number starting from $2.

```
cat test.txt | awk 'BEGIN{ RS = "" ; FS = "START\n" }{print $2}'

#Test
#Test
#Test
A    B    1
A    B    2
A    C    1
A    C    2

cat test.txt | awk 'BEGIN{ RS = "" ; FS = "START\n" }{print $3}'

#Test
#Test
#Test
A    B    1
A    B    1
A    A    2
A    C    3
```